# Colour Cells using RGB values "Error 13"

Tags: excel, rgb, vba

Very simple vba problem, not sure where it is going wrong, but:

```
Range("J21").Select
For tastetherainbow = 1 To 1000
    skittle = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    Selection.Interior.Color = skittle        
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select    
Next
```

The cell containing each appropriate skittle value contains an RGB code in the form RGB(r,g,b) , exactly as it should be for the VBA. I have tested it by copy pasting the cell's value into Selection.Interior.Color = *paste* without issue, but I get a "type mismatch" when it just uses skittle.

In fact, the only reason I am using skittle as a variable is that I had the same issue when I used `Selection.Offset(0,2).Value` to set the colour.

Rather lost! Could you let me know how to fix it, and *why* I have this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys, I modified it and cheated a little... This is running as part of a *much* larger macro, so I decided to just make the array of R, G, and B values explicit, and do it this way. From reading online Victor it says that RGB() expects values as integers - Long is more efficient but does the same thing nowadays no? Here is a working version. Couldn't have done it without you both thank you very much!

```
 Sub ColourMeImpressed()

    Dim Skittler As Long
    Dim Skittleg As Long
    Dim Skittleb As Long

    Dim tastetherainbow As Long


    With Sheets("Converter")
        For tastetherainbow = 21 To 1000
            Skittler = .Cells(tastetherainbow, "G")
            Skittleg = .Cells(tastetherainbow, "H")
            Skittleb = .Cells(tastetherainbow, "I")
                Skittle = RGB(Skittler, Skittleg, Skittleb)
                .Cells(tastetherainbow, "J").Interior.Color = Skittle
        Next tastetherainbow
    End With

    End Sub
```

For those interested, here is a screenshot of the final result:

[image]

Comment: `RGB()` expects the value of each parameter `(red, green, blue)` as `Integer` because the max value you could provide for each one of them is `255`, so there is actually no gain in declaring your `Skittle` variables as `Long` in this case. `RGB()` however, will evaluate as a `Long` value, which is the value you provide in the `.Interior.Color` parameter. For instance, if you go to the immediate window of your editor and type `?RGB(200,215,227)` it will output `14931912` and you couldn't store that in a `Integer` variable. Hope this clears it out a little bit

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended not using `Select` , `Selection` and `ActiveCell` , instead I preffer to start the `For` loop from Cell "J21" and just advance the row by 1.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CellColors()

Dim Skittle As Long
Dim tastetherainbow As Long

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For tastetherainbow = 1 To 1000
        Skittle = .Cells(tastetherainbow + 20, "L").Value
        .Cells(tastetherainbow + 20, "J").Interior.Color = Skittle
    Next tastetherainbow
End With

End Sub
```

**Edited Code**: converts the cell string format of "RGB(0,0,74)" to 0,0,74, then using the `Split` function putting the `String`s into 3 elements of an array.
Then calculating `Skittle` `Long` numeric value using `CInt` and the ***RGB*** method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CellColors()

Dim Skittle As Long
Dim CellRGBStr  As String
Dim RGBInd() As String
Dim tastetherainbow As Long

With Sheets("Sheet3")
    For tastetherainbow = 1 To 1000
        If .Cells(tastetherainbow + 20, "L").Value <> "" Then

            ' use a string to store the "RGB(0,0,74)" as 0,0,74
            CellRGBStr = Mid(.Cells(tastetherainbow + 20, "L").Value, 6, Len(.Cells(tastetherainbow + 20, "L").Value) - 7)

            ' split the CellRGBStr to 3 array elements
            RGBInd = Split(CellRGBStr, ",")

            ' calculate the value of Skittle (using the RGB method)
            Skittle = (CInt(RGBInd(0))) ^ 3 + (CInt(RGBInd(1))) ^ 2 + (CInt(RGBInd(2))) ^ 1
            .Cells(tastetherainbow + 20, "J").Interior.Color = Skittle
        End If
    Next tastetherainbow
End With

End Sub
```

Another way to calculate `Skittle` is with the `RGB` function:

```
Skittle = RGB(CInt(RGBInd(0)), CInt(RGBInd(1)), CInt(RGBInd(2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I will give your answer a shot, but I am not sure what your method changes other than getting rid of the inefficient select statements. If this does work and solves the mismatch error - why does it do so? I am trying to improve!

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the Mismatch error - I am scratching my head here...

Comment: @LukasLjungstrom according to your code, you have number values in Column "L", from rows 21 to 1000, and you want to have the cell background color in Column J according to the value of the relevant cell in Column L, right ?

Comment: Indeed I do, or 1000 is just a placeholder for the moment before I bother to create a variable. You are precisely correct. In debug mode, when I hover over the skittle variable it shows the correct value, yet yields a runtime error when it is used to define the colour - in both your and my methods.

Comment: does your cells in Column L have number values from 0 to 16,646,655 ? It's RGB, so it's (255,255,225) , values from 0 to 255^1+255^2+255^3 . What values are you stroing in column L ?

Comment: Column L stores complete RGB codes in the format RGB(r,g,b), as should be used to define the colour. 

The first three values for example are currently (surrounded by quotes): "RGB(0,0,94)"; "RGB(7,8,99)"; "RGB(14,16,104)" - When copied as text into the vba and used as colour codes they work perfectly. All of them are between 0 and 255

Comment: @LukasLjungstrom this is actualy totaly different than how I thought you store the values - you are using `String` . I usualy use the numeric value, let me work on that...Inside the cells you have "RGB(0,0,94)" ? with the quotes at the begining and the end ?

Comment: I understand, but it is in the original question! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @LukasLjungstrom try the edited code under `Edited Code`

Comment: @LukasLjungstrom, just to add an explanation to what is going on (in case you haven't understood yet what Shai Rado is trying to do), the problem is that when you get the value of your cells and store them in a variable, it is being stored as a `String`, so your code understands it as the literal `"RGB(0,0,94)"`(for example) instead of reading it as `RGB(0,0,94)` and convert it to its proper value, thus causing the Type Mismatch error (receiving a `String` instead of a `Long`. Shai Rado is working on the logic to treat this in his code

Comment: Thanks for all the help, unfortunately I still get the same error at line 20 where you set the value of Skittle. I will have a play and get back to you

Comment: And thank you very much Victor for the explanation, it means I can learn instead of just mindlessly copying the work of those better than me!

Comment: @LukasLjungstrom why are you getting an error at line 20 ? your `For` loop starts at row 21, no ?

Comment: Line 20 of the code you posted i.e.   Skittle = (CInt(RGBInd(0))) ^ 3 + (CInt(RGBInd(1))) ^ 2 + (CInt(RGBInd(2))) ^ 1

But I posted a version that resolved the issues I had so it worked in my limited use-case at least. I really appreciate the time you've put into helping me

Comment: @LukasLjungstrom do you want me to try and solve it ? cause I see below that you have your own answer, and you decided to split the `RGB` to 3 adjacent cells - smart decision

Comment: Thanks for all the help Shai, but at this point solving it elegantly would only be an intellectual effort - the macro is only designed to handle a small number of values (>100), and any increases in efficiency from getting rid of select statements etc would be measured in fractions of fractions of seconds. I have learned a lot from this process and your help! I have included a screenshot so you can see the fruits of your labour.

Answer (score 0):

```
'little modification is required in your code as follows 
Range("J21").Select
For tastetherainbow = 1 To 1000
    skittle = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(skittle)        
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select    
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer- I confess I didn't see this until I had posted my own. Unfortunately this would have yielded - had everything played along -
RGB(RGB(x,y,z))  as Skittle was already defined as the complete RGB code in the form RGB(x,y,z).
-
Additionally we discovered that Skittle was being inputted as string and RGB requires an integer (or a long?). 
-
Thanks for your help nonetheless!